# SWIFTUI 2, SWIFTUI 3 - MACOS: Why TextField's onCommit closure is always trigger every time I switch to another tab

Tags: macos, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

- **My code**: I use `onCommit` closure to be able to perform an action by pressing the *Enter key* when the `TextField` is being focused.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var text = ""

  var body: some View {
    TabView {
      TextField(
        "",
        text: $text,
        onCommit: { print("onCommit") } // I have a problem here
      )
        .tabItem {
          Text("Tab 1")
        }

      Text("Tab 2")
        .tabItem {
          Text("Tab 2")
        }

      Text("Tab 3")
        .tabItem {
          Text("Tab 3")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

- **My problem:** The `onCommit` closure is also always triggered when I switch to another tab, making my App perform an unexpected action.
- **My questions:**

  1. This is the *bug* or the *feature*?
  2. Is there a way to avoid the `onCommit` trigger every time I switch to another tab?

Answer (score 1):

- I have found the solution by following [the deprecated message](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield/init(_:text:oneditingchanged:oncommit:)-588cl).

> **Deprecated**
>
> Use `init(_:text:prompt:)` instead. Add the `onSubmit(of:_:)` view modifier for the `onCommit` behavior, and `onFocus(_:)` for the `onEditingChanged` behavior.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var text = ""

  var body: some View {
    TabView {
      TextField("", text: $text)
        .onSubmit {               // new api
          print("onCommit")
        }
        .tabItem {
          Text("Tab 1")
        }

      Text("Tab 2")
        .tabItem {
          Text("Tab 2")
        }

      Text("Tab 3")
        .tabItem {
          Text("Tab 3")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

- `onSubmit` doesn't trigger every time I switch to another tab.

Comment: 'onSubmit(of:_:)' is only available in iOS 15.0 or newer

Answer (score 0):

#### onCommit

> An action to perform when the user performs an action (for example, when the user presses the Return key) while the text field has focus. [https://developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield/init(_:text:oneditingchanged:oncommit:)-588cl)

It is by design. When you change tab, the TextField ***loses focus***. Therefore, **onCommit** is called.

**onCommit** is also called when the user presses the **Return** key.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more precise and I also found the answer in the link you gave me. thanks